# How to fit border the hero sprite

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

How can i remove the white color in this picture?

[[image: MYHERO.png]]

Comment: Like pointed already in the answer below, you have to use clear background... But to preserve transparency, you have to save the image with .png extension (rather than .jpeg).

Answer (score 0):

If your image itself has white background, you should get an image with clear background. If you want the change the bg color of UIImageView you can do it in properties inspector in storyboard. thanks.